# Criar arquivo doc. Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application

Tags: microsoft-word

Estou com uma aplicação legada, em Visual Studio, que gera arquivos .*doc*, utilizando **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application**.

A aplicação vai adicionando linhas, negritando algumas palavras, mas algumas vezes, o texto fica truncado.

Já procurei por código ascii e até agora não encontrei nada.

Obrigado,

Comment: você poderia exemplificar com seu código, para podermos visualizar melhor

Comment: de preferência a parte do código onde realiza a leitura das informações (de onde ele busca) e a parte da escrita do arquivo.

Comment: Segue o código:

Comment: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document worddoc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();

Comment: string nl = System.Environment.NewLine;

worddoc = wordapp.Documents.Add();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = worddoc.Paragraphs[1].Range;
wordapp.Application.Selection.Font.Size = 10;
wordapp.Application.Selection.Font.Name = "Courier New";
wordapp.Application.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft;
wordapp.Application.Selection.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0;

Comment: StringBuilder strCabecalho = new StringBuilder();
  strCabecalho.Append("----------------------------------------------------------------------" + nl);
  strCabecalho.Append(" P R O T O C O L O    " + "( " + pesqPge.nmeArquivo + " )");

                //Insere os dados da publicação
  wordapp.Application.Selection.TypeText(strFormatacao.ToString());
                //Insere uma quebra de página

Comment: Parece que o problema ocorre nesse: 
wordapp.Application.Selection.TypeText(strFormatacao.ToString());